# Excel if statement for first day of the month

Tags: excel

I'm trying to meticulously track interest growth and monthly payments on a loan in excel. Instead of manually putting in the amount for each first day of the month, is there a way to write an excel if statement so that it will be a certain value for the first day of a month and zero on all other days?

Sort of like: `=IF("day is first day", $100,$0)` That way I can drag the formula all the way down. Worth noting that inside the quotation marks will be a cell number that points to the column directly left of the formula with a date in it.

So like this:

```
|   Date   | Payment | Balance |
|:--------:|:-------:|:-------:|
| 01/30/16 |      $0 |   $1000 |
| 01/31/16 |      $0 |   $1000 |
| 02/01/16 |    $100 |    $900 |
| 02/02/16 |      $0 |    $900 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(A2=Date(Year(A2),Month(A2),1),100,0)
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I wasn't aware of these functions ("Date", "Year", etc)

Answer (score 3):

You need the `DAY` Function.

`=IF(DAY(A2) = 1,100,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DAY() function to get the day number

```
=IF(DAY(A1)=1,100,0)
```